# Select each letter in a file, then find its ASCII value (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

My code:

```
from random import randint
import string

def menu(): #Main menu
    choice = int(input("Encrypt [1] Decrypt [2] Exit [3]: ")) #Allows choice
    print("")

    if choice == 1: #Goes to the function for each option
        encrypt()
    elif choice == 2:
        decrypt()
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Good bye")

def encrypt(): #Encrypt
    print("Enter the name of the file you wish to encrypt(with the file 
    ending)") # Need the file ending to work
    targetFile = input("-> ")
    f = open(targetFile, "r+") #Opens the file as 'f'
    print(f.read()) #Prints the text in the file

    key = []
    for i in range(0,8):
        chrKey = randint(33,126)
        newKey = str(chr(chrKey))  #converts ascii number to text
        key.append(newKey)
    print('')
    print('Your eight character key is:')
    print(''.join(key))

    keyTotal = 0
    for j in range(0,8):
        newValue = ord(key[j])
        keyTotal += newValue
    print(keyTotal)

    offset = keyTotal/8-32
    offset = int(offset)
    print("Offset", offset)

    with open(targetFile) as f:
        characters = 0
        for line in f:
            wordslist=line.split()
            characters += sum(len(word) for word in wordslist)
    print(characters)
    characters = int(characters)

    cypherText = []
    with open(targetFile) as f:
        cypherValue = 0
        for g in f):
            cypherValue = ord(g)
            cypherText.append(g)
        print(cypherText)


menu()
```

For the .txt file you can use anything shouldn't make a difference.

What I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to turn each letter in the file except for spaces into its ASCII code
and then add the offset factor to each value, convert it into its ASCII character then put it all into the cypherText list.

Comment: Specify what problem you are facing while executing the code

Comment: There is no issue while executing the code, my question is on how to convert each character into its ASCII value in the "sample.txt" file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ConAar2, if you want to convert each character of your text into their corresponding ASCII values, then you can use `ord()` function in Python to get the ASCII values for characters

Documentation of `ord()` function as in Python Docs

> ord(c)
>
> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the
>   Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode
>   object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string.
>   For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97, ord(u'\u2020') returns
>   8224. This is the inverse of chr() for 8-bit strings and of unichr() for unicode objects. If a unicode argument is given and Python was
>   built with UCS2 Unicode, then the character’s code point must be in
>   the range [0..65535] inclusive; otherwise the string length is two,
>   and a TypeError will be raised.

Below is the sample code to test this one:

```
string = input("Enter character: ")
for w in string:
    print(ord(w), end=' ')
```

Code Output:

```
Enter character: Hello there!
72 101 108 108 111 32 116 104 101 114 101 33
```

In the above code, the spaces entered in the input text would also return its ASCII value. To prevent this (as required by the question), we can run an if-else statement as follows:

```
string = input("Enter character: ")
for w in string:
    if ord(w) != 32:  # ASCII code of space character is 32
        print(ord(w), end=' ')
    else:
        continue
```

Code Output:

```
Enter character: Hello there!
72 101 108 108 111 116 104 101 114 101 33
```

Hope this answer helps you.